# how to get numberOfRowsInSection from NSFetchedResultsController with sectionNameKeyPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an entity with attribute "group", cause I want to group into 2 sections the list of my entities by "group" (either 0 or 1)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * group;
```

In my fetchedResultsController, I specify sectionNameKeyPath as "group"

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
    initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
    sectionNameKeyPath:@"group" cacheName:nil];
```

How can I return the number of rows in each section inside the method below?  I am getting error below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] 
        numberOfObjects];
}
```

Also I tried this, got the same error:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]
    objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

Note that I implemented this method as well:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`? If you don't implement it, the tableView assumes you have 1 section, which would lead to this exception if the fetchedResultsController does not have any sections (i.e. it has no objects).

You must return `[sections count]` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}
```

---

If you always want to show two sections you have to check if the fetchedResultsController has the requested section. If the fetchedResultsController does not have this section, don't ask it for the number of objects in this action.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger count = 0;
    NSInteger realNumberOfSections = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
    if (section < realNumberOfSections) {
        // fetchedResultsController has this section
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section];
        count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    else {
        // section not present in fetchedResultsController
        count = 0; // for empty section, or 1 if you want to show a "no objects" cell. 
    }
    return count;
}
```

if you return something other than 0 in the else you have to change `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as well. Similar to this method you have to check if the fetchedResultsController has an object at the requested indexPath.

Comment: I implemented that method but I returned specifically 2 cause I want to show 2 sections on first view of the scene even if there are no records yet

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 2;
    }

Comment: You can't do it like this. I'll add an edit for this.

Comment: How should I force to show 2 sections at the start if I don't have any records for the entity that I want to group yet?

Comment: in the same method? There are a couple of methods you have to change if you return a "wrong" value in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. For example `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and all others that ask the fetchedResultsController for an object or a section.

Comment: you said i need to put this inside the numberOfSections method... return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections count];... but with that it's not showing any section at all... the reason why I hardcoded it to 2.  also I hardcoded the values returned in, for example, titleForHeaderInSection cause I know upfront that I have 2 sections... however, only when I commented these 2 lines and return 1 for both (cause I need to show 1 cell for each section for adding), then i got no error:::  
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>...
count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]...

Comment: My mistake. The if has to be different, of course we can't rely on the UITableViewDataSource method, because we return the "wrong" value there. I made another edit.

Comment: ok, now I got no error... i'll continue now to create my "add function" to add record on each section... thanks a lot for your help, and i hope i can ask you again if i encounter error after i made my "add" functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   let section = fetchedResults.sections?[section]
   let sectionCnt = section?.numberOfObjects

   return sectionCnt!
}
```

First get the section. The count the # of objects in it.

Note: For this to work, the fetchedResults object must know how you divide your data into sections! That's achieved at the time of the fetch request. In this line, pass it the CoreData attribute name you use to divide section:

```
fetchedResults = NSFetchedResultsController(
    fetchRequest: fetchRequest, 
    managedObjectContext: managedContext,
    sectionNameKeyPath: "CD_Attribute_Name_GoesHere",
    cacheName:nil
)
```